# Oracle - Subquery in IF Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
if USER IN (SELECT user_id from user_maint where roll = 12) THEN
        p_status := 'W';

ELSE 
        p_status := 'A';
END IF;
```

It gives the error: `Error(332,16): PLS-00405: subquery not allowed in this context`

How to make subquery in the IF clause?

Comment: What's USER ? Is it a variable?

Comment: That's a function which returns the user_id from the current Oracle session, @Kazi.

Comment: No problem, @Kazi :)

Comment: *How to make subquery in the IF clause?* makes the assumption that this is something PL/SQL can do. What you really want to do is test a condition using a query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Select` first, use in `if` next.

```
declare
  l_user_id user_maint.user_id%type;
  p_status  varchar2(1);
begin
  select user_id
  into l_user_id
  from user_maint
  where roll = 12;

  if l_user_id = user then
     p_status := 'W';
  else
     p_status := 'A';
  end if;
end;
/
```

Though, a simpler option is

```
select case when user_id = user then 'W'
            else 'A'
       end
into p_status
from user_maint
where roll = 12;
```